# Как создать ветку и сделать её основной?

Tags: github, git-branch, pull-request

У меня по заданию необходимо создать пустой репозиторий
Затем установить CRA
Закоммитить в ветку level-2
Но в репозитории должна быть еще ветка main - основная
И в конце сделать pul request

Я сделала

```
 1. git init
 2. git remote add origin https://github.com/alexandrinka/movies-explorer-frontend.git
 3. git checkout -b level-2
 4. git add .
 5. git commit -m "frontend"
 6. git push -u origin level-2
```

В ветку level-2 код закоммитился
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как создать вторую ветку Main, чтобы она была основной и в конечном итоге работал pull request?

Comment: https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/configuring-branches-and-merges-in-your-repository/managing-branches-in-your-repository/changing-the-default-branch

Comment: Посмотрите на это, похоже на Ваш запрос https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51274430/change-from-master-to-a-new-default-branch-git